# In R: "regcomp error: 'Missing ')'" --' regexec problems

Tags: regex, r

```
product <- c('Model1','Model2','Model3')
price <- c(NA, NA, NA)
pricelist <- data.frame(product, price)
```

Using this data frame I run the following for loop to scan a document(called unformatted text in the code below) for the price and insert the price into the data frame

```
   for (i in 1:nrow(pricelist))
        {
        p <- regexec( paste(pricelist[i,1], "(.*?)", "([0-9]+\\.[0-9][0-9])", sep = ""), unformattedtext)
        p2 <- regmatches(unformattedtext, p)
        p3 <- sapply(p2, function(x) x[3])  
        pricelist[i,2] <- p3
        }
```

If I run this loop I get an error with `regexec` saying this-> regcomp error: 'Missing ')''
BUT if insert the values for i manually, using the exact same code, it functions correctly. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? If it matters I'm using plyr for rbind.fill to get those NAs in my initial data frame.

Comment: runs fine for me, but had to make up a junk `unformattedtest`

Comment: ...restarted R and problem went a way, I feel stupid. Thanks for giving me code confidence tho!

Comment: Nevermind...error is back, and now isn't going away.

Comment: The first argument to regexec cannot be a vector. If you wanted to get multiple calls to `regexec` then use `lapply` or `sapply`. And please don't capitalize R function names if they are not already capped.